# Can't reboot device using runtime.exec

Tags: android, exec, reboot

For some reason I cannot reboot Android devices using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/reboot");. I have tried the following code on 3 devices now without luck. One was built from rowboat-android source. The other two are the Motorola Droid Pro (Rooted, stock) and the HTC Ledgent (Rooted, Cynogen Mod). All devices are running Android 2.2 Froyo.

Does anyone know why? su works as well as the Super User application is visible. I should note various other shell commands do work, like netcfg (chmod' to 777) and ls.

```
public static boolean executeCommand(SHELL_CMD iShellCmd){
        String cmd = null;
        String line = null;
        String fullResponse = null;
        Process lPs = null;

        Log.d(Global.TAG,"--> !!!!! Running shell command");

        if (iShellCmd == SHELL_CMD.restart_device){
            cmd = "reboot";
        }

        Log.d(Global.TAG,"--> About to exec: " + cmd);

        try {
            lPs = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            lPs = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/reboot");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(lPs.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lPs.getInputStream()));

        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(Global.TAG,"--> Command result line: " + line);
                if (fullResponse == null){
                    fullResponse = line;
                }else{
                    fullResponse = fullResponse + "\n" + line;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(Global.TAG,"--> Full response was: " + fullResponse);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does the command work if you run it from the terminal emulator? Did you try just `reboot` instead of `/system/bin/reboot`?

Comment: Calling 'reboot' did not work and locks up the application and an ANR (Force quit) is displayed. If I call reboot on the device using adb shell, the system is rebooted properly. Then I need to restart the system to be able to issue shell commands using runtime.exec again.

Comment: what's the logcat after the force quit? Search for anything after the word `FATAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after weeks of searching:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you've obtained root permission on your device, you can do any of the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c","reboot"});
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot"});
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot"});
```

Probably better to test all three scenarios in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "su /system/bin/reboot" instead of su and the command on different lines. That might help :)

Comment: you mean .exec("su\n/system/bin/reboot");
or do you mean 
.exec("su
/system/bin/reboot");

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button to be pressed try:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
             try {
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot"});              
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }               
        }
    });
```

By the way for this code to work the button has to be called button1.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot"}` i changed the `"/system/bin/su"` part to just `"su"` and then it worked for me.

Like this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot"});`