# Reboot a rooted android device

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app for personal use that can reboot or poweroff my android device, whichever will work, but this code does not work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c reboot");
```

I have already added the REBOOT permission in the android manifest

But if I execute this code inside ADB shell, my device reboots.

Here is my code:

```
public void reboot() {
    Process rebootProcess = null;
    try
    {
        rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c reboot");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // We waitFor only if we've got the process.
    if (rebootProcess != null)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = rebootProcess.waitFor();
            Log.i("result", "" + result);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Executing the command under ADB shell only works if I type su, press enter then type reboot. It doesn't work on a single line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603221/cant-reboot-device-using-runtime-exec?rq=1 maybe

Comment: Different settings of PATH variable can bite you when operating in difference applications/users.  You can use the "which" command to find the full paths to "su" and "reboot" on your system, then include these in your Java code.  On Debian I have "/bin/su" and "/sbin/reboot", but you can expect different for Android.

Comment: su and reboot are located in /system/bin. Tried adding the path to the command in my code. It still does not work

Comment: You should pass each option as separate argument to `exec`. Question referenced by @RC has answers, that show how to do that correctly.

Comment: I have tried the following variations:  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/system/bin/su", "-c", "/system/bin/reboot"});
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/system/bin/su", "-c", "reboot"});
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "reboot"});
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "/system/bin/reboot"});` still nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my git repo, take the rebootLib file, as that's all you need and have a look at the sample if you run into any issues.

The Reboot permission can only be used by system apps (signed with the system key), it would also require android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in your manifest to function.  The permission is never called by your app and not required as you are using root.

[Repo Link](https://github.com/TimSayers/RootRebooter/)